# Are there any papers about the calling contour (minor third, vocative chant) in Italian?

Tags: phonology, reference-request, romance-languages, intonation

As indicated in the answers to "[Is it common to use the minor third for calling someone?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/824/111)", "many European languages" use this type of chanted falling contour, but the examples all come from English, German and French. Working on Romance Languages, I am interested in any information about the usage of this contour in Italian.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [Interactive Atlas of Romance Intonation](http://prosodia.upf.edu/iari/index.html) (created by Pilar Prieto and others) to be helpful. It includes a whole bunch of useful resources and references, including [interactive maps](http://prosodia.upf.edu/iari/mapa.html) that allow you to click on a city and hear audio recordings of different utterances elicited from speakers in that city. Vocatives are one of the intonational contour categories that were included.

Browsing through the Italian recordings, I encountered many instances of the minor third (and some major thirds and some major seconds). The survey made a distinction between the "vocative" and the "insistent vocative" (you can read in the methodology section about how the two were elicited), and interestingly there were some cases where one involved a minor third at the end and the other didn't and some cases where both involved a minor third but the "insistent vocative" just placed the minor third interval higher in the speaker's vocal range.